# Android: Traffic stats (daily unique user, monthly unique user) for applications using app id

Tags: android, mobile, statistics, google-analytics, analytics

How can I find daily unique user, monthly unique user, weekly unique user for app using app id ?

Answer (score 0):

Android Market only tracks number of downloads and active installations, which apparently also counts any updates installed. To track unique users you should probably build this into your app with a pingback to your own servers. Here's [a post](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/03/identifying-app-installations.html) on how to count devices reliably.

Answer (score 0):

One way is doing like Peter [said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5453104/android-traffic-stats-daily-unique-user-monthly-unique-user-for-applications/6041580#6041580), and building you own infrastructure. This is the best one if you need to know your user data at a very grained level.

Another solution (cheaper) is to use the [Google Analytics SDK for Android](http://code.google.com/mobile/analytics/docs/android/). It's a hack supported by google that allows to use the GoogleAnalytics platform to track mobile apps data, but its cheap and fast to implement (and scale).